# jQuery mobile Multiselect doesn't update selected attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile

I have a jQuery mobile custom multiselect, but when I select one item we have the list of items on the HTML `select` tag, but it is not updated with the `selected` attribute.

[Using the **Multiple selects** example of the page](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.0a4/docs/forms/forms-selects.html):

```html
<div data-role="fieldcontain" class="ui-field-contain ui-body ui-br">
  <label for="select-choice-9" class="select ui-select">
    Choose shipping method(s):
  </label>
  <div class="ui-select">
    <a href="#" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" data-theme="c" class="ui-btn ui-btn-icon-right ui-btn-corner-all ui-shadow ui-btn-up-c">
      <span class="ui-btn-inner ui-btn-corner-all">
        <span class="ui-btn-text">
          Rush: 3 days, Express: next day
        </span>
        <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrow-d ui-icon-shadow"></span>
      </span>
      <span class="ui-li-count ui-btn-up-c ui-btn-corner-all" style="">
        2
      </span>
    </a>

    <select name="select-choice-9" id="select-choice-9" multiple="multiple" data-native-menu="false" tabindex="-1">
      <option>Choose options</option>
      <option value="standard">Standard: 7 day</option>
      <option value="rush">Rush: 3 days</option>
      <option value="express">Express: next day</option>
      <option value="overnight">Overnight</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Is there a way for making it add the `selected` attribute by default ?

Comment: You can get the selected values by using $('#select-choice-9').val(); . Why do you need selected attribute ?

Comment: What code are you using to retrieve the `selected` option values from the `select`?

Comment: I am using ASP.Net MVC and I would like to have the format the DefaultModelBinder, it usually accepts the pattern bellow:

Lets say: the one of the option's name should have the name A[0].B[1].C[2].D[3], where A,B,C and D are array objects, is also something I am trying to achieve with this control, and if I could select the values that have the attribute selected would be a good idea. But if doesn't I would need to get the span's value, split it and search each option attribute and update it by attaching an event after pop-up is closed.

Comment: You are using JQuery mobile not JQuery UI

Comment: @Tito I tried a sample and the DefaultModelBinder accept a List<string> of values for a select with no problems. You don't need the selected attribute at all but I posted a solution just in case you need it.

Comment: Hey @devconcept, you are correct, the DefaultModelBinder doesn't check the "checked"'s value, it works with the jquery mobile code, I don't know how it translate the span to the values, is there any hidden field ?

Comment: There are no hidden fields. The code you posted include some of the boilerplate JQM generates to render the widget. [By default](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Forms/The_native_form_widgets) only `<select>`, `<input>` and `<textarea>` tags get sended when submiting a form to the server. If you write a simple `<select>` tag JQM will auto-enhance it to display the selection menu but only the `<select>` tag is important when sending to the server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JQuery Mobile by default will not update the `selected` attribute in response to the user's input. You can keep the selected values in sync with the attributes with the following code.

```
$(function () {
    $('select').on('change', function (evt) {
        var options = $(evt.target).children('option'),
            current;
        for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
            current = options[i];
            if (current.selected === true && !current.hasAttribute('selected')) {
                options[i].setAttribute('selected', '');
            }
            if (current.selected === false && current.hasAttribute('selected')) {
                options[i].removeAttribute('selected');
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Remember that this will work for all the selectmenu widgets that you already have in the DOM. If you add one programmatically you also have to add the event handler to that widget.